# Not Found when serving express static file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to access to a page of my web application. I created the server with expressJs and I serve the route by using `app.use(express.static())`.

Here is my tree :

```
client
    |___Consultation
    |    |___Parametrage
    |    |    |
    |    |    |___parametrage.html
    |    |    |___parametrage.css
    |    |    |___parametrage.js
    |    |
    |    |___consultation.html
    |
    |___index.html
app.js
```

In the `app.js` file, I have this :

```
app.use('/MPS', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.use("/Consultation", express.static(__dirname + '/client/Consultation'));
app.use("/Parametrage/", express.static(__dirname + '/client/Consultation/Parametrage/'));
```

The line `app.use('/MPS', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));` work fine : when I go to `http://localhost:8080/MPS` the page `index.html` is displayed.

But when I go to `http://localhost:8080/Consultation` or `http://localhost:8080/Parametrage`, none of `consultation.html` or `parametrage.html` is displayed.

I have this error : `Cannot GET /Consultation/`

I don't know how to fix it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a specific `html`-page in your url the default is `index.html`. Since there are no index files in Consultation/Parametrage subfolders you see above error.

If you request it with

`http://localhost:8080/Consultation/consultation.html`

it should work fine. Alternatively you can rename `consultation.html` to `index.html` as well and request it with `http://localhost:8080/Consultation`.

Comment: Thank you ! I renamed my html file with index and it work better !

Answer (score 1):

Your location `/client` has the file `index.html`
Try putting the same file in other locations.
Basically rename `consultation.html -> index.html` and `parametrage.html -> index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Go with the following syntax for other routes

```
app.use('/admin', function (req, res, next) {
  // GET 'http://www.example.com/admin/new'
  console.dir(req.originalUrl)
  // '/admin/new' console.dir(req.baseUrl)
  // '/admin' console.dir(req.path) 
 // '/new' next() 
});
```

or

locate index file
`http://localhost:8080/Consultation/consultation.html`